# Layer renders twice with EPSG:5514 in WMTS OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, epsg, wmts

I am trying to create a WMTS layer in OpenLayers with the following properties:

- Url: http://geoportal.cuzk.cz/WMTS_ORTOFOTO/WMTService.aspx
- Matrix set: jtsk:epsg:5514
- Projection: EPSG:5514

I am using the projection definition from http://epsg.io/5514 (the default one).

The resulting tiles contain two layers: 1 positioned correctly and another one in the wrong position. Does anyone have idea why is this happening?

[image]

Here is also a codepen that I have created https://codepen.io/bampakoa/pen/yWyLog

Comment: `http://epsg.io/5514 (the default one).` epsg.io isn't the definitive reference, the definitive reference is the epsg.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange effects can be produced by some reprojections.  This is the world with 2 Europes and Africas when projected in EPSG:5514

[image]

A simple workaround would be to limit the EPSG:3857 extent of your EPSG:5514 layer when it is reprojected to EPSG:3857

```
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    opacity: 1,
    extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([10,40,30,60],'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),
    source: new ol.source.WMTS(/** @type {!olx.source.WMTSOptions} */ (options))
  })
```

Comment: Actual extent for EPSG 4326 is [12.09, 47.73, 22.56 ,51.06] (see https://epsg.io/5514).

Comment: @TomazicM  In some cases a buffer may be useful.  Maps sometimes go beyond the defined extent of their projection, e.g. overview maps in EPSG:27700 https://epsg.io/27700 are usually extended west into negative coordinates to include the whole of Ireland

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.